# need an oracle query joining 2 tables with 2 conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a master table

```
Select * from Table_Master
```

> PKID EMPNo Name
>
> 1    101   aaa
>
> 2    102   bbb
>
> 3    103   ccc

```
Select * from table_TXN
```

> TXN_PKID  MASTER_FKID  EMPNo  REMARKS
>
> 1   1     101 NA
>
> 2   2         500     ITS A WRONG ENTRY
>
> 3         3       123     THIS iS ALSO A WRONG ENTRY

I need a query which will fetch records:

> 2   2         500     ITS A WRONG ENTRY
>
> 3         3       123     THIS iS ALSO A WRONG ENTRY

Something like:

```
select * from Table_Master a, table_TXN b where a.PKID = b.TXN_PKID BUT a.EMPNo <> b.EMPNo
```

Comment: One of the tables is only a temporary working table, right? You don't really store redundant data, do you? If these tables *are* real tables, then simply drop EMPNo from table_TXN and you're fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic works fine as a join:

```
select t.*
from table_TXN t join
     Table_Master m
     on t.txn_pkid = m.pkid and t.empno <> m.empno ;
```

Your code sample would work if you replaced `BUT` with `AND`.  However, don't use implicit joins.  Explicit `JOIN`s were introduced in SQL more than two decades ago; the explicit syntax is clearer, more powerful, and accepted by all databases.

Comment: wont it give me repeated data? I have huge data will not be able to trace for duplicated rows.. so just wanted to be sure

Comment: Of course it will give you repeated data.  Whenever you `select *` from more than one table, you are guaranteed to get the joining column twice.  Plus if you are selecting the primary key fields, using distinct won't help either.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . (1) This query only selects columns from one table; (2) It seems highly unlikely that a join on something called `pkid` would produce unexpected duplicate rows.

Comment: No it did not give any repeated data.. I got the data with proper condition combination